# parse curl_exec() json response properly

Tags: php

I have found a solution, however, I am looking for a better one. Here is a situation:

I am sending a request with the following code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($message));
$result = curl_exec($ch); # Here I am receiving a response.

if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Now, the `$result` is the response that I have received and I want to read it. It is in JSON format. Looks like this:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 1234567890,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 10,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    },
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}
```

At first I tried parsing it using `json_decode($result)` but that got me an error, so I tried to parse it as array of elements with `json_decode($result, true)` which worked just fine.

Now, I don't need any other information besides `results[]` array with all the errors in that particular order.

So I was able to get it with the following code:

```
$responses = array();
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($decoded as &$item) {
  # During first iteration, in order to find array of "results" I have to perform this check
    if (is_array($item)) {
        foreach ($item as &$in_item) {
            foreach ($in_item as &$in_in_item) {
              $responses[] = $in_in_item;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

With this kind of iteration through multiple arrays I was able to get all the `"InvalidRegistration"` messages and then use them for my needs.

This solution works of course, however, I was wondering if there a better, more concise way of achieving same result.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$decoded['results']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to iterate to get `InvalidRegistration`. just take the results in an array to get `InvalidRegistration` errors.

```
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);

$invalidRegistration = $decoded['results'];
var_dump ( $invalidRegistration );
```